# Can I use confstr to set up two nameservers?

Tags: dns, nameservers, qnx

I am trying to set two dynamic nameserver IP addresses in my QNX system.  I have been able to use confstr to set up an address by setting a `_nameserver=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` string into _CS_RESOLVE.  Then res_search returns the correct IP address for a given name.  I actually  have two questions:

1. How do I set up two nameservers (primary and secondary) using setconf?
2. If the nameserver IP addresses change, can I just call setconf again to change them while my application is running?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [QNX docs](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/utilities/r/resolv.conf.html), your confstr() setting needs to contain:

```
nameserver_1.2.3.4
nameserver_5.6.7.8
```

(i.e. one line per nameserver, with a maximum of three)

If the nameservers change, you'll probably need to call `res_init()` to force the resolver library to use the new settings.